# Discord bot not responding with my prefix

Tags: discord, command

Please help me with this code I made for my Discord server.
I have no idea what I'm doing and I need to figure out why isn't the bot responding when I use !aczping (or when I change it just to ! prefix) it does nothing!
Thank you for your help

```
import discord
import random
import os
from itertools import cycle
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!acz")
status = cycle(['!acz // Senkuu by Rubix', 'acz!help - Made by AntsCzech', '!acz // Alpha v0.11.2, Made in Python (discord.py/repl.it)'])

bot = Bot("!acz")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@tasks.loop(seconds=20)
async def change_status ():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("Command executed")

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)} ms')

@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error,commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Chybí část příkazu, zkus to znovu.')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!acz ahoj'):
        await message.channel.send('Hoj hoj!')

    if message.content.startswith('!acz help'):
      await message.channel.send ('**Voláš o pomoc?** \nzatím ti nabídnu jen tyto příkazy: \n\n`!acz ahoj` Pozdravím tě! \n`!acz help` Pošlu ti tento seznam')

    elif message.content.startswith("!users"):
      await message.channel.send(f"""# počet Uživatelů na serveru: {id.member_count}""") 

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands need at least the message intents

Just change your client instance definition line to this

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!acz", intents=intents)
```

Also your bot = Bot(...) Makes no sense as you're defining your bot instance as `client`. I would suggest you rename the instance to bot though.